# Vue.js @click is registering only half of the time

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to toggle a class when clicking on a select box in order to animate a dropdown arrow. It works, but only half of the time. In the screencast below you can see how the arrow if reflecting the state of the class "expanded".

[image: video cast of the behavior]

This is the HTML:

```
<div :class="{ expanded: compActive }" class="select-wrapper">
  <select v-model="companyId" @click="compActive = !compActive" @change="changeComp" name="company" id="company" >
    {% for company in companies %}
        <option value="{{ company.id }}">{{ company.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

In my Vue.js instance there is just a simple data entry of compActive: false

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    compActive: false
  },
  ...
```

EDIT: added source styles

SASS

```
.select-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 450px;

  &:after {
    content: url("../img/arrow_right.png");
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 22px;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: .2s;
  }

  &.expanded {
    &:after {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform-origin: 40% 45%;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you provide the CSS content?

Comment: It seems fine on template. Can you check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y095596ml9)?

Comment: @Gasanov Seems like this is Chrome bug! Your sandbox has the same problem behavior as my own code, but it works as intended in FireFox. Seems like I will have to rewrite my question. Thanks for your help